# Drupal resource links

Tags: support, faq

What are the links to Drupal resources that can help in understanding how Drupal works, and how to develop a Drupal project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Documentation links

- [Drupal.org Community Documentation](http://drupal.org/documentation); this online community documentation is written and maintained by the Drupal community.
- [API reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal); it contains the documentation for all the functions/classes implemented from Drupal core modules; it contains also the documentation for the Views module.
- [Lullabot Drupal API Reference](http://api.lullabot.com/); it contains also the documentation for functions/classes implemented in most of the third-party modules.
- [IIIEPE API Reference](http://api.iiiepe.net/); it's an alternative site that include the documentation for both Drupal core, and third-party modules.

Answer (score 1):

#### Lullabot videos

- [Understanding Drupal](http://store.lullabot.com/products/understanding-drupal)
- [Administering Drupal](http://store.lullabot.com/products/administering-drupal)
- [Site Building With Drupal](http://store.lullabot.com/products/site-building-with-drupal)
- [Drupal Performance & Scalability](http://store.lullabot.com/products/drupal-performance-scalability)
- [Drupal SEO](http://store.lullabot.com/products/drupal-seo)
- [Learning CCK](http://store.lullabot.com/products/learning-cck)
- [Learning Views](http://store.lullabot.com/products/learning-views)
- [Drupal Module Development](http://store.lullabot.com/products/drupal-module-development)
- [Theming Basics](http://store.lullabot.com/products/theming-basics-for-drupal)
- [Advanced Theming](http://store.lullabot.com/products/advanced-theming-for-drupal)
- [Introduction to jQuery](http://store.lullabot.com/products/introduction-to-jquery)
- [jQuery and JavaScript in Drupal](http://store.lullabot.com/products/jquery-and-javascript-in-drupal)

Answer (score 1):

#### SiteGround tutorials

- [Why use Drupal](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/drupal-tutorial/why_drupal.htm)
- [How to install Drupal through Fantastico](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/drupal-tutorial/drupal_installation.htm)
- [How to manage Drupal users](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/drupal-tutorial/drupal_users.htm)
- [Access control in Drupal](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/drupal-tutorial/drupal_access_control.htm)
- [How to use Search Engine Friendly URLs in Drupal](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/drupal-tutorial/drupal_sef.htm)
- [How to backup Drupal](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/drupal-tutorial/drupal_backup.htm)

Answer (score 1):

#### Acquia Webinars (it may require registering on the site)

- [Three Powerful Tools for Improving the Performance of your Drupal Site [June 21, 2012]](https://www.acquia.com/resources/acquia-tv/conference/three-powerful-tools-improving-performance-your-drupal-site-june-21)
- [State of HTML5 Support in Drupal [June 14, 2012]](https://www.acquia.com/resources/acquia-tv/conference/state-html5-support-drupal-june-14-2012)
- [Drupal for the .NET programmer [June 6, 2012]](https://www.acquia.com/resources/acquia-tv/conference/drupal-net-programmer-june-6-2012)
- [Responsive Web Design with Drupal and the Omega Theme [March 28, 2012]](https://www.acquia.com/resources/acquia-tv/conference/responsive-web-design-drupal-and-omega-theme-march-28-2012)
- [Define and Design Once – Distribute to any Device through Responsive Design [February 28, 2012]](https://www.acquia.com/resources/acquia-tv/conference/define-and-design-once-distribute-any-device-through-responsive-0)