# Community page for Drupal Books/Learning Materials

Tags: discussion

Is there any community pages for list of Good Drupal books / learning materials with very helpful review from some Drupalers. I mean seriously Good books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Drupal resource links](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214/drupal-resource-links) which at the moment doesn't include any link to books. It could be helpful if somebody knows of any good Drupal books, and makes a post with links to Amazon pages. (Similar pages on other sites would be good too.)

Answer (score 2):

You can find the list of Drupal books here https://drupal.org/books , but before that have a look at this [Guides](https://drupal.org/documentation) and [Learn By the Drop](http://learnbythedrop.com/archives) and also check out this [Online Training Videos](http://drupalonlinetraining.com/).